# Cannot trace the error source when parsing an XML file

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

This is the code:

```
   var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(QuoteAndOfferCollection));
    try
    {
        using (var file = File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            offers = (QuoteAndOfferCollection)serializer.ReadObject(file);
        }
    }
    catch (SerializationException sex)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(log, "Deserialization failed - " + sex);
        return;
    }
```

And this is the error I get:

```
xmlDeserialization failed - System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object of type Services.Dto2.QuoteAndOfferCollection. The value '' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: The value '' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToInt32(String s)
   at System.Xml.XmlConverter.ToInt32(String value)
```

I am not able to trace the **''** part.

Comment: "SerializationException sex" interesting naming convention :)

Comment: Forgot about that, I just put the capital letters of the exception type followed by 'ex'.

Comment: Did you check for `InnerException` ? if so, search for all `int` properties of your `QuoteAndOfferCollection` type and its members in the xml file, the corresponding attribute might be missing or have value ""

Comment: @maziar-taheri The `InnerException` has a System.Xml.XmlException inside. And the messsage `{"The value '' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'."}` Also, I was hoping I didn't have to do the file parsing by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the exception and get the value of `file.Position`. That will give you some idea of where in the file the offending line is. You can do better than that if you wrap a custom stream around the `FileStream` and keep track of the number of lines read.

You might also be able to create an `XmlReader`, and pass that to `ReadObject`. When you catch the exception, examine the reader's properties. It might tell you exactly what line had the error.

But you'll need move where the exception is caught. That is, rather than:

```
try
{
    using (stream)
    {
        // deserialize
    }
}
catch
{
}
```

you want to write:

```
using (stream)
{
    try
    {
        // deserialize
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```